# fetch links using the value

Tags: jquery-selectors

In JQuery, how can I get all the links with value like User% (ie) User23 & User 24 in this example.

```
<TBODY>

<tr>

<td class="box6B">

<a href="mytestpage.htm#79391606">79391606</a>

</td>
<td class="box2B">

<a href="mytestpage.htm#79391606">User23</a>
</td>
</tr>

</TBODY>
<TBODY>

<tr>

<td class="boxt7B">

<a href="mytestpage.htm#79391607">79391607</a>

</td>
<td class="box2B">

<a href="mytestpage.htm#79391607">User24</a>
</td>
</tr>

</TBODY>
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could do something like this:

```
$('a:contains("User")')
```